# Good FOSS Duplicate File Finder For OSX

Tags: macos, file-management

Today I embarked on the journey of taking a few of my computers new and old and consolidating like files to like folders. Now I need to find the duplicates. There are so many files I dont want to do this by hand (or keyboard?). Does anyone know a free duplicate file finder for os x? preferably Open Source if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[duff](https://github.com/jcburley/duff) ... I found it to be faster than fdupes, and it's easier to use in scripts. You can get it via Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

I like [FSlint](http://en.flossmanuals.net/FSlint/Introduction) on Linux, with any luck it'll build on OSX. Unfortunately I don't know of any good FOSS duplicate *image* finder, I have to use Windows ones like XNView.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [fdupes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes) from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). It's a generic duplicate file finder for the command line.